# Defining an array type with a set number of elements

Tags: types, f#

I want to create an array that can have no more and no less than three elements.  Is there a way to do that in a type definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
type Array3<'T> = private Array3 of 'T [] with
    member this.Elements = let (Array3 xs) = this in xs
    static member Create x y z = Array3 [|x;y;z|]
```

Now it is ensured that everytime you see a value of type `Array3`, the value has exactly three elements:

```
let myArray = Array3.Create 1 2 3
myArray.Elements |> printfn "%A"
```

You can read more about this technique in this [book](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/ddd/).

Answer (score 6):

No, that wouldn't really be an array any longer. You can however create a tuple of three elements:

```
let triple: int * int * int = (1, 2, 3)
```

A tuple can also have elements of different types and can be destructured directly instead of through pattern matching since its exact shape is known at compile-time:

```
let (a, b, c): int * float * string = (1, 2.7, "3")
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on both @Nghia Bui 's and @glennsl 's answers, you can define your own `Triple` type using a tuple of three elements for type safety:

```
type Triple = Triple of int * int * int 
    with
    static member inline (+) (t1, t2) =
        match t1, t2 with 
        | Triple (a1, a2, a3), Triple (b1, b2, b3) -> Triple (a1 + b1, a2 + b2, a3 + b3)
    //add other functionality like map, fold, etc you'd normally expect from Arrays  
let t1 = Triple (1, 2, 3)
let t2 = Triple (4, 5, 6)
t1 + t2 //val it : Triple = Triple (5,7,9)
```

Or you can make it generic:

```
type GenericTriple<'a> = GenericTriple of 'a * 'a * 'a
    with
    static member // etc...
```